# PHP Array Ascending Sort

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I've and array, I want to sort this array ascending order by [sys_title] key index. What should I do?

```
[0] => Array
(
    [sys_id] => 9
    [sys_title] => Checklist
    [sys_home] => /cp/system/chl/
)

[1] => Array
(
    [sys_id] => 8
    [sys_title] => Bakery Ordering System
    [sys_home] => /cp/system/bos/
)
```

Expected Result should be like this:

```
[0] => Array
(
    [sys_id] => 8
    [sys_title] => Bakery Ordering System
    [sys_home] => /cp/system/bos/
)

[1] => Array
(
    [sys_id] => 9
    [sys_title] => Checklist
    [sys_home] => /cp/system/chl/
)
```

Comment: use usort() function

Comment: Can you please explain?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

Answer (score 1):

You can try this piece of code:

```
usort($data,function($a,$b){
    return strcmp($a['sys_title'],$b['sys_title']);
});

print_r($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your array name is $a then:

```
$tmp = Array();
foreach($a as &$ma) {
    $tmp[] = &$ma["sys_title"];
    array_multisort($tmp, $a);
}
```

Result will be

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [sys_id] => 8
            [sys_title] => Bakery Ordering System
            [sys_home] => /cp/system/bos/
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [sys_id] => 9
            [sys_title] => Checklist
            [sys_home] => /cp/system/chl/
        )

)
```